# .Net framework 4.0 issue on windows 10 os

Tags: frameworks

I am trying to install one windows application on windows 10 platform. My application need to install Dot Net Framework 4.0 when trying to install then error message will appear and say to install Dot Net Framework 4.0 after that when I try to install Dot Net Framework 4.0 then error message shows me Dot Net Framework 4.0 already install in this system so I can't understand what is the issue with that.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 included Dot Net Framework 4.0 and above.

Windows 10 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.6 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

So you don't need to install as already "Installed"...

Comment: Thanks But my application not install same error message appear when I try to install application

Comment: Are you able to check the windows application source code. Any checking on dot net version at the source code?

Comment: yes definitely I have source code but I tried to install another system with same configuration it was work.

Comment: Is there any checking .net system in your source code. Try comment it out and run Since the .net in the machine already.Just for debugging purpose.